# Laptop doesn't boot to bios

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, bios

I have a laptop(Turbox M765SU). It's really old.

I found it yesterday and decided to use it as a NAS and/or testing environment for programs, etc.

I remember it was booting just fine, though it's monitor was dead.

I took an HDMI(tried with VGA too) and I tried to boot it, but I realized that the led for the hard drive start's to blink(like it should I guess) and then it goes blank(I don't think it should).

If I remember correctly the monitor had a problem with the backlight or something like that and I had figured out how to see some minimum details to get an idea of what I do, but it doesn't seem to boot at all, not even into bios.

The external display doesn't get signal(is on power save mode, it does it when no data is sent to it)

The fans seem to work and I think the CPU should work too because when I touched it, it felt a bit warm.

I also tried to plug a USB that has a light that indicates when something is reading from it, the results are the same, it starts blinking and then goes blank

I don't care about display, I want to at least boot from a live USB, the live USB will have an SSH server start when the OS boots so I just need a way to force it to boot (if there is a way).

Any help is appreciated.